# variable i'm not splicing is being spliced

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a function that takes in an array, and prints versions of the array with one number missing. For example, if the array were `[1,2,3]`, it would print `[2,3]`,`[1,3]`, `[1,2]`. So I'm making a variable `tempSeq`, setting it equal to `Sequence`, printing it with `Document.write()`, and then resetting `tempSeq` to the original `sequence`. For some reason however, the variable `sequence` is being spliced. Not sure why this is happening, and any help would be appreciated!

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var tempseq = sequence;
  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    tempseq = sequence;
    tempseq.splice(i, 1);
    document.write("(" + tempseq + ")");
  }
  return tempseq;
}

almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

The function name is odd because ultimately the function is doing something else.

Comment: `sequence.map((_,i) => sequence.slice(0, i).concat(sequence.slice(i+1)))`

Comment: `tempseq = sequence` is not a copy...they both reference exact same array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is actually saying 'call the "sequence" array also "tempseq"'

```
var tempseq = sequence;
```

and it is not saying 'clone the "sequence" array into "tempseq" (if you expect this behavior). Then splice actually operating on `sequence` array

```
tempseq.splice(i, 1); // equal to sequence.splice(i, 1)
```

Just clone the array:

```
// instead of
// var tempseq = sequence;
var tempseq = sequence.slice();
```

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var tempseq = sequence.slice();
  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    tempseq = sequence;
    tempseq.splice(i, 1);
    document.write("(" + tempseq + ")");
  }
  return tempseq;
}

almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: I guess a `tempseq = sequence.slice();` inside the for loop will result, what the OP wants.

Comment: Fixed the problem! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign tempseq = sequence tempseq is still the same array, it is just a reference so splice effects both. Use reduce to create a copy of the array without the item at i

```js
function almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) {
  var tempseq = sequence;
  for (let i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
    const tempseq = sequence.reduce((results, item, index) => index === i ? results : [...results, item], []);
    document.write("(" + tempseq + ")");
  }
  return tempseq;
}

almostIncreasingSequence([10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```